# How to using sql query row data and parent-path string?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

**DB version:Oracle 11g**
My DB Table create secript:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  parentId INTEGER,
  name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO test (id, parentId, name) VALUES (1, 0, 'A');
INSERT INTO test (id, parentId, name) VALUES (2, 1, 'B');
INSERT INTO test (id, parentId, name) VALUES (3, 1, 'C');
INSERT INTO test (id, parentId, name) VALUES (4, 2, 'D');
INSERT INTO test (id, parentId, name) VALUES (5, 4, 'E');
```

**now,how to using sql query like this result:**

[image]

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/342fa0/25

This works for ORACLE 11g

```
SELECT
    t1.id, t1.parentId, t1.name,
  CONCAT ( DECODE (t5.name, NULL, '',  CONCAT(t5.name, '->')),
  CONCAT ( DECODE (t4.name, NULL, '',  CONCAT(t4.name, '->')),
  CONCAT ( DECODE (t3.name, NULL, '',  CONCAT(t3.name, '->')),
  CONCAT ( DECODE (t2.name, NULL, '',  CONCAT(t2.name, '->')),
   T1.NAME   ) )))   
   AS parent_path

FROM
test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t1.parentId
LEFT JOIN test t3 ON t3.id = t2.parentId
LEFT JOIN test t4 ON t4.id = t3.parentId
LEFT JOIN test t5 ON t5.id = t4.parentId
ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Credits: Mark's base answer for mysql has been modified for Oracle-11G

Answer (score 1):

This query will do it for you:

```
SELECT
t1.id, t1.parentId, t1.name, 
  CONCAT(
    IF (t5.name IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(t5.name, '->'), ''),
    IF (t4.name IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(t4.name, '->'), ''),     
    IF (t3.name IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(t3.name, '->'), ''),
    IF (t2.name IS NOT NULL, CONCAT(t2.name, '->'), ''),
    t1.name) AS parent_path
FROM
test t1
LEFT JOIN test t2 ON t2.id = t1.parentId
LEFT JOIN test t3 ON t3.id = t2.parentId
LEFT JOIN test t4 ON t4.id = t3.parentId
LEFT JOIN test t5 ON t5.id = t4.parentId
```

You just need to recurse through the potential parents.  This will only go 4 levels deep, so if you need more you'll have to add additional left joins.  You can also see this in action in this fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/342fa/5